# Spring Batch Quick Start not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying Spring Batch Quick Start from Spring site ([Spring Boot Quick Start](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)) but I can't get it to work:

- end() method in SimpleJobBuilder (see job method in BatchConfiguration class) is missing
- When I run the main class (removing the reference to end method), Spring Boot starts up (I see the logs in the console) but the job it's not getting executed; from docs around the web I saw that the job should start as soon as the SpringApplication is run

There is something terribly wrong in Spring Batch Quick Start or there's something terribly wrong in what I'm doing?

I think it's useless to publish my code: it's copied from Spring Batch Quick Start...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that little sample might be incomplete. For instance you would need `@Enable AutoConfiguration` in order to get a job to run on start up. There's a more extensive example here, if it helps: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/.

Comment: Yep! Good suggestion! I had to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` and then change `SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args)` to `SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args)`

Comment: The sample should be fixed now. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In step one of the Spring Batch quick started, the guide asked to add this(the dependency below) into the pom.xml but it errored when there's no version provided. Reason being is that the guide didn't include the parent dependency. So the annotations and the java objects do not know where to look.

I got the quick guide to work by directly including the spring-boot-starter dependency. Then the app ran.. A lot of the spring framework guides seem to assume a strong knowledge in project management and comprehension tool.

```
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```